# How to format $filter('date') as timestamp in millisecond?

Tags: angularjs

I like to use `$filter('date')('2017-08-23', 'timestamp')`, what is the correct syntax to format it to timestamp in millisecond? The document here (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) does not have any relevant record.

Comment: do you want to get the date from millisecond?

Comment: You write your own filter. Or, if you already have a Date object in the model, you just write {{ date.getTime() }}